# Scraping Glassdoor Reviews with Python Selenium: How to click on Continue Reading in a Glassdoor Review to get to the Advice to Management data

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I´m scraping Glassdoor reviews and can´t reach the data, that is written to advice to management. I tryed to reach it the same way I reach the data for "pros" and "cons".

```
    def scrape_pros(gdReview):
        try:
            res = gdReview.find_element(By.XPATH, './/span [@data-test="pros"]').text
        except Exception:
            res = 0
        return res
       
    def scrape_cons(gdReview):
        try:
            res = gdReview.find_element(By.XPATH, './/span [@data-test="cons"]').text
        except Exception:
            res = 0
        return res
```

But the data can´t be found, because first the "Continue Reading" needs to be opened(by clicking on it), so the class for "Advice to Management" will be found.
[html code of continue reading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmnmo.png)

```
<div class="
                        v2__EIReviewDetailsV2__continueReading 
                        v2__EIReviewDetailsV2__clickable 
                        v2__EIReviewDetailsV2__newUiCta mb 
                    ">Continue reading</div>
```

I tried to click "continue reading" in many different ways.
Here are two examples I tried many combinations of:

```
gdReview.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div[@class="v2__EIReviewDetailsV2__continueReading v2__EIReviewDetailsV2__clickable v2__EIReviewDetailsV2__newUiCta mb"]').click()
gdReview.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div[@class ="row mt-xsm mx-0"]/preceding-sibling::div[text()="Continue Reading"]').click()
```

But those didn´t work.

I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Update the question with the text based relevant HTML.

Comment: Please provide the HTML in a code-block, and not as screenshot (get with ctrl+u)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element with text ***Continue Reading*** is within a `<div>` element with the *textContext* as *Continue reading*.

---

### Solution

To click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH* and the *textContext* as *`Continue reading`*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(., 'Continue reading')]"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and the *v2__EIReviewDetailsV2__continueReading* class:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'v2__EIReviewDetailsV2__continueReading') and contains(., 'Continue reading')]"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and the *v2__EIReviewDetailsV2__clickable* class:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'v2__EIReviewDetailsV2__clickable') and contains(., 'Continue reading')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```